# How to combine two animations in css of a bouncing ball

Tags: html, css

Combine two animation that make bouncing ball animation in css

I tried separate animation of both x and y elements and combine it but the result produced not bouncing but bouncing in particular diagonal and didn't give me the expected result.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users review [ask] for tips on asking questions that best invite the community to engage and assist.  It is generally expected that questions include a [mcve] to provide critical context; this should be accompanied by a clear explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, and how the code is failing to accomplish your goal.  Add these, and you're be much more likely to get a useful answer to your inquiry.  Good luck, and happy coding!